# How can i put a placeholder into @Html.HiddenFor textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.StateAbbreviation, new { @placeholder = "State" })
```

the textbox is a dropdown field, so I use `@Html.HiddenFor`

but the state didn't show up in the textbox.

I just want to show the hit to the user.

Comment: My brain hurts. You're calling `HiddenFor`, but then you're saying it's a textbox *and* a dropdown field. That's three totally different things. If it's truly a hidden field, `placeholder` does nothing, because nothing at all is displayed. If it's a select, `placeholder` does nothing, because it's not applicable to a select.

Answer (score 0):

`HiddenFor` helper generate `<input type="hidden" />` if you want to generate texbox use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StateAbbreviation, new { placeholder = "State" })
```

Anyway your code looks right except you don't need to escape `placeholder` like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.StateAbbreviation, new { placeholder = "State" })
```